# What does if (!$variablename) do in PHP?

Tags: php, operators, not-operator

I know that `!=` is "not equal", but what does it mean when you have this:

```
if(!$something)
```

My first guess is something to do with exceptions, but a look around google did not return anything.

So what does this do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whatever is in the variable is [converted to a Boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (the variable itself of course remains intact), and then a NOT operation (`!`) is done on the resulting Boolean. The conversion will happen because `!` is a [Logical Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and only works on Boolean values.

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

**Tip:** If the variable is not expected to be Boolean, you might want to use something more specific like `isset($variable)`, `empty($variable)`, `$variable === ''`, etc. depending on what you want to check for. Check the manual for details.

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as:

```
if((bool)$something != true) {
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: This one is the best answer, other forget to mention that the test is casting bool on $something to check it, which is very important depending on what is in $something. I'd recommand reading carefully the doc about casting to booleans in php

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!$something) {
```

is an equivelent of

```
if ($something == false) {
```

Comment: False. For example `!"0"` is true, but `"0" === false` is not.

Comment: @Jeroen No, actually `==` is what happens here. The variable will be converted with `!` to Boolean. So the strict equality will not return the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Checks to see whether $something is falsy.

Answer (score 1):

It just means "If not something".

```
if (!false) {
   this_happens_because_not_false_is_true();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(!$variable)` is the same as `if($variable == false)` so it checks if $variable is false
Look at @bažmegakapa [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012822/what-does-ifvariblename-do-in-php/11012868#11012868) to see which values are considered false.

Answer (score 1):

It converts the variable into `boolean` equivalent of the variable. This can be given in a few cases:

```
<?php

    // Case 1: $variable is boolean
    $variable = true;
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(false)

    // Case 2a: $variable is a positive integer
    $variable = 5;
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(false)

    // Case 2b: $variable is an integer other than 0
    $variable = 0;
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(true)

    // Case 2c: $variable is a negative integer
    $variable = -5;
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(false)

    // Case 3a: $variable is string
    $variable = "Hello";
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(false)

    // Case 3b: $variable is empty string
    $variable = "";
    $variable = !$variable; // Changes to false;
    var_dump($variable); // bool(true)
?>
```

In short, it makes the opposite of the `empty()` function! :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well, not exactly the opposite of `empty()`.

Comment: There is of course. I just checked the manual link I posted in my answer, and then the manual of `empty()` and there are some differences (haven't tried myself).

Answer (score 0):

Checks to see if `$something` is false.

Comment: Not really. That would be `$variable === false`.

Answer (score 0):

it check if `!$something` is false or you can understand it like (if not$something) then {//this will execute } and if $something is present then the this will not enter in the if

Answer (score 0):

!$variable is the 'Not' logical operator
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

it takes a boolean value and flips it. True becomes false and false becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

I met following code once

```
 if (!$this->error) {
      return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }
```

I thought "if no error , why false?? Thats wrong!" Because i thought "!" operator equals "NOT".
And swaped returns. But everytime error condition codes ran.
Then learned. "!" operator converts variables to boolean. Empty variables converted to "false". And "if" statements with "!" operator run like that "if this boolean is false, return false, else return true.! :)

Comment: When an if else statement is used to return true and false the statement can be simplified to return either the if condition or the reverse of the if condition depending on the order of the return statements in the if else. In this case `return !!$this->error;`

Answer (score -3):

```
if($somethin == ""){
}

Or

if($somethin != ""){
}
```